# Uncaught TypeError: row.child.hasClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm creating row details for DataTables without Ajax.
I do somethink like this for show:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function format ( name, value ) {
        return '<div>Name: ' + name + '<br />Value: ' + value + '</div>';
    }
    var table = $('#servicetable').DataTable({
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 10,
    });

    $('#servicetable tbody').on('click', 'button.test', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
        row.child( format( tr.data('child-name'), tr.data('child-value') ) ).show();

        if ( row.child.hasClass('shown') ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
});
```

When I click button for open - everythink is ok, but when I click again for hide I getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: row.child.hasClass is not a function
```

What's bad?
Here is demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmc700bt/)

Comment: `child` is function. you already use it as function. `hasClass` can be applied to result of this function call, but not the function itself. (as you call `show()`)

Comment: Yes, `row.child` does not exists for the open child row, does it? Move '         `row.child( format( tr.data('child-name'), tr.data('child-value') ) ).show();` into the  `else {` scope....

Comment: just do `row.child().hasClass('show')`

Comment: @DavidDomain : Does Jquery  have Child() method ?

Comment: @YoYo - Not jQuery, but the dataTable row object has a `child()` method.

Comment: @DavidDomain oh okie

Comment: @DavidDomain If I do this, I getting this: https://jsfiddle.net/tmc700bt/1/

Comment: and what about https://jsfiddle.net/tmc700bt/2/

Comment: @gaetanoM Now in div, what I want show, I have data from row but I won't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdn764ar/)

Datatable child [doesn't seem to provide a hasClass](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()) function.
Also I think you were checking for 'shown' class in the wrong element. I also removed `row.child.show()` on opening, it is already done before the if statement.

```
       if ( tr.hasClass('shown') ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
```